# Display data from a database in a HTML page using django views

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a problem with creating a view with data from the database. I created a view that should download data from videos (var films) and display them, unstable

views.py

```
from .models import Films

def index(request):
    filmy = Films.objects
    return render(request, 'films/index.html',{'filmy':filmy})
```

index.html

```
<h1>Films</h1>
{% for film in films.all %}

{{filmy.summary}}

<br>
{% endfor %}
```

models.py

```
class Films(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.summary
```

I only have a blank page.

Answer (score 1):

Your views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

from .models import Films

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    films = Films.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'films/index.html',{'films':films})
```

In index.html

```
{% for film in films %}
    <p> {{film.summary}} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

I hope that helps.